# Find basis and dimension of system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the homogeneous system of linear equations

$$
2x_1 + 2x_2 + 4x_3 - 2x_4 = 0,
$$
$$
x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 + 2x_4 = 0,
$$
$$
-x_1 + x_2 + 4x_3- 2x_4 = 0.
$$

I row reduced to 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -.625\\0 & 1 & 0 & 1.875\\0 & 0 & 1 & -1.125\end{bmatrix}$$

And came up with the general solution:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-.625 \\ 1.875 \\ -1.125 \\ t\end{bmatrix}$$
  t = any real number

So I believe that the basis will be:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}4\\1\\4\end{bmatrix} + {\begin{bmatrix}-2\\2\\-2\end{bmatrix}}$$

Dimension = # of vectors in the basis so It would be 4.

My question is did I handle the free variable $x_4$ correctly in my answer? Or should I exclude the last vector, ${\begin{bmatrix}-2\\2\\-2\end{bmatrix}}$, because they are all free variables, which would make the Dimension = 3

Answer (score 1):

If the RREF is $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -.625\\0 & 1 & 0 & 1.875\\0 & 0 & 1 & -1.125\end{bmatrix}$$

And came up with the general solution:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.625t \\ -1.875t \\ 1.125t \\ t\end{bmatrix}=t\begin{bmatrix}0.625 \\ -1.875 \\ 1.125 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

From here, can you state the dimension and a basis for the solution space now?

Comment: The basis is all of the equations in the homogenous solution and the dimension would be 3?

Comment: just checking, basis of what are we talking about?  solution space?

Comment: yes, the solution space

Comment: the solution is a multiple of the same vector, that vector forms a basis.

Comment: I'm sorry, you lost me there. multiple of what vector? Why is it the same vector?

Comment: I have rewritten the solution for $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$, they are all multiples of $(0.625, -1.875, 1.125, 1)$.

Comment: why is $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ solution have t in all of them? Is it because it is a free variable? There seems to be a blinding gap in my knowledge and I don't know what it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85850/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-evan-kim).